# how java final variable made behind the scenes

Tags: java, final

I know that when I declare a final variable it cannot be changed. 
Can someone explain what happens behind the scenes  that make it not changeable?

Comment: Nothing at all. It is just enforced by the compiler.

Comment: "when I declare a final variable it cannot be charged" -> if this is supposed to mean "changed", you are wrong. it's value can be changed, unless it's either a primitive type or an instance of an immutable type.

Comment: The variable cannot be re-assigned, which I guess is what igor means. Anyway, it's just the compiler doing that, no magic there.

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz: indeed, but way too much people think that the fact that they can not be reassigned, means that their value can not be changed.

Comment: That's perhaps a problem with java's primitives, they tend to compilcate everything since they behave differently. Makes it harder for beginners.

Comment: It's not only enforced at compile-time. Trying to change it via reflection will lead to an exception. The runtime also knows that the field is final.